# CSS Scrolling over fixed div, background disappearing

Tags: css

I have a fixed div followed by a content container below that I hope will scroll over the fixed div and hide it.
The container's content does scroll over but for some reason the container's background seems to slip underneath the fixed div.

Before scrolling
[image: Before scrolling]

After scrolling
[image: After scrolling]

So far I've tried messing with z-index in different ways but without any joy...

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8mq0droh/

Any suggestions on how to change the CSS hugely appreciated.
Thanks!

```css
#map
{
    position:fixed;
    background:red;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    height:100px;
}

.text
{
    position:relative; 
    left:0;
    right:0;
    padding:10px;
    top:100px;
    
}

.content-wrapper {
  background:yellow;
  z-index:3;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="map">
  fixed content
</div>
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="content-body">
    
    <div class="text">this should slide over the fixed content when scrolling (including the yellow background)<br />here text <br />here text </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: z-index:1 to the fixed element? or position:relative to the yellow box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why people are confused with your explanation. Slide under or slide over makes sense. You want the yellow object to slide **OVER** the red object.

`z-index` only works if you have a `position` set on the object. [Here](https://coder-coder.com/z-index-isnt-working/) are some other things to look out for.

In saying this, I have tweaked your code to work accordingly. I've also added some comments so that you can see what I've added or removed.

```css
#map
{
    position:fixed;
    background:red;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    height:100px;
}

.text
{
    position:relative; 
    left:0;
    right:0;
    padding:10px;
    
    /**removed the below**/
    /*top:100px;*/
    
}

.content-wrapper {
  background:yellow;
  z-index:3;
  display:block;
  
  /**added the below**/
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map">
  fixed content
</div>
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="content-body">
    
    <div class="text">this should slide over the fixed content when scrolling (including the yellow background)<br />here text <br />here text <br />here text <br />here text <br />here text <br />here text <br />here text <br />here text <br />here text <br />here text <br />here text <br />here text <br />here text <br />here text <br />here text <br />here text <br />here text <br />here text <br />here text <br />here text <br />here text <br />here text <br />here text <br />here text <br />here text <br />here text <br />here text <br />here text <br />here text <br />here text <br />here text <br />here text <br />here text <br />here text <br />here text <br />here text <br />here text <br />here text <br />here text <br />here text <br />here text <br />here text <br />here text <br />here text <br />here text <br />here text <br />here text <br /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You'll see instead of `top: 100px` I'm now using `margin-top: 100px` - this is now the buffer between the two objects.

Comment: Amazing - I would have been there all week! I didn't know about the subtle difference the margin-top would have vs top. Thanks for the lesson!

Answer (score 1):

Simply add sticky to position make the a div sticky to top of the page.

Like so:

```css
#map
{
    position: fixed;
    background:red;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    height:100px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.text
{   
    left:0;
    right:0;
    padding:10px;
    top:100px;
    
}

.content-wrapper {
  background:yellow;
  margin-top: 100px;
  position: relative;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="map">
  fixed content
</div>
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="content-body">
    
    <div class="text">this should slide over the fixed content when scrolling (including the yellow background)<br />here text <br />here textthis should slide over the fixed content when scrolling (including the yellow background)<br />here text <br />here text this should slide over the fixed content when scrolling (including the yellow background)<br />here text <br />here text this should slide over the fixed content when scrolling (including the yellow background)<br />here text <br />here text this should slide over the fixed content when scrolling (including the yellow background)<br />here text <br />here text  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This will work just fine. You just have to make the fixed div sticky so it sticks at the top of the screen.

Comment: And the other elements will go under it

Comment: Hmm - I need the yellow div to slide *over* the re one, this slides it under. Playing with the z-index doesn't seem to work? Thanks for your help.

Comment: here you go i have edited the answer now it will work new time be more specific about what you want!

Comment: You ticked the wrong question I gave the right answer